# g++ compiler error with templated base class member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, clang++

I'm trying to compile some Microsoft Visual C++ code using g++. Now I've come across a compiler error which I really can't understand. The (simplified) code looks like this:

```
template<int X> struct A {
    template<class Ret> static Ret call() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template<int X> struct B : A<X> {
    int f() {
        return A<X>::call<int>();
    }
};
```

When I try to compile this with g++ (version 4.4.5), I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In member function int B<X>::f(): 
main.cpp:16: error: expected primary-expression before int 
main.cpp:16: error: expected ; before int
main.cpp:16: error: expected unqualified-id before > token
```

If I remove the template type (Ret) from method A::call, the code compiles just fine. Can anybody see whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `template` keyword:

```
return A<X>::template call<int>();
```

`call` is a dependent name, meaning that its signification depends on a template parameter, which is not known when the compiler process `f()`. You need to indicate that `call` is a function template by prefixing it with the `template` keyword.

The same thing happens when you try to access a nested type: you need to add the `typename` keyword to indicate that the name denotes a type:

```
template <typename T>
struct A { typedef int type; };

template <typename T>
void f()
{
    typename A<T>::type i = 0; // notice "typename" here
}
```

And sometimes you even need to mix both:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    struct inner { };
};

template <typename T>
void f()
{
    typename A<T>::template inner<int> var;
}
```

The use of these two keywords is thoroughly explained in the answers to this question: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/) (thanks to @Björn Pollex for finding the link).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/) provides an in-depth explanation when and why this is necessary.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Thanks, I was actually looking for this exact question :)!

Answer (score 5):

`A` is a template, and without knowing `X` the compiler can't determine the contents of `A<X>`. Especially it doesn't know that `call` will end up being a template.

To tell that to the compiler you have to use the `template` keyword:

```
template<int X> struct B : A<X> {
    int f() {
        return A<X>::template call<int>();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify that the function you're calling is a template, as it's part of a template class.  The compiler is not aware that any given `A<X>` has a template function named `call`, and therefore you need to help it.

```
template<int X> struct B : A<X> {
    int f() {
        return A<X>::template call<int>();
    }
};
```